# Wrong label on Choropleth map

Tags: python, plotly, label, choropleth

My Choropleth map is showing the wrong label.
Here is my sample code:

```
#Mental Illness Prevalence Choropleth Map
fig2 = px.choropleth(df_prevalence,
                    locations='Code',
                    color='Percent',
                    color_continuous_scale='mint',
                    hover_name='State',
                    locationmode='USA-states',
                    labels={'Percent':'Percent'},
                    scope='usa')


fig2.add_scattergeo(
    locations=df_prevalence['Code'],    ###codes for states,
    locationmode='USA-states',
    text=df_prevalence['Code'],
    mode='text')

fig1.update_layout(
            title={'text':'Adults with Serious Thoughts of Suicide in the Unites States by State, 2020',
            'xanchor':'center',
            'yanchor':'top',
            'x':0.5})
fig1.show()
```

My label says "IncidentPerInhabitant" but I would like it to say percent
[image]

Comment: fig1 and fig2 are mixed up, please correct the code. Is everything unified with fig2?

Comment: I can't reproduce your situation because I don't have the data, but try the following: add the following code before `fig.show()`. Override. `fig.layout.coloraxis.colorbar.title.text = 'percent'`

Comment: silly mistake I didn't see. This fixed it, thanks!